# How to remove #anchor (location.hash) from url when linking from other page within website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have to converted a scrolling single landing page theme to work with WordPress. It awesomely removes the `#anchor ids` from the URL.

Everything was working fine until the client asked to add another page but to keep the *same header navigation*.

Now I'm linking from an inner page `(mysite.com/page)` with `href="/#anchor"`. This basically works, but there are two bugs I can't wrap my head around.

First, it no longer removes the `#anchor` from the URL - whatever anchor was clicked on stays in the URL indefinitely. Secondly, the alignment is slightly off (it's fine when navigating from the home page).

The `history.pushState` method sort of works to remove the # from the URL, but this is buggy too - it creates an extra step in the browsing history, and probably doesn't work on enough browsers.

**Please, Sir, is there a way, using `javascript (or php)`, to force `href="/#anchor"` to first go to index.php (top), then scroll nicely to the anchor?**

But careful NOT to reload the page when navigating from the home page. If this is possible, it would likely fix the alignment issue, as well.

I have come to believe that nothing is impossible - **so don't let me down! :-)**

Answer (score 0):

So if you use replaceState that doesn't add an extra step in the history. As you say though the browser support is limited, specifically IE http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

Why would you not want the hash to be in the URL?

Comment: Mostly don't want the hash because it's ugly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEU99/)

```
<a href="#anchorName">Goto</a>

<a name="anchorName">Come to me</a>


(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url=document.URL.split("#");
    var ancher=url[1];
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $('#'+ancher).offset().top
         }, 5000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```